# Testing of application Active Directory auth

Tags: desktop-application

I have a windows application with Active Directory authentication. I need to test a login\logout\another login flow.

But I have only 1 AD account in the domain, and I can't get another login for testing for auth switching (test accounts are restricted by our policy).

Can you suggest some trick or some online service for AD account testing?

**UPD**

Application read some AD properties for current AD user, so no access restrictions should be in this issue.

Comment: Please list the AD settings for users in your system.  In general you can't properly test something they refuse to give you permission to test properly...

Comment: I test the app which read AD account property of current user.

Comment: Can you utilize two different machines?  Virtual or physical...

Comment: And include both to domain with 2 different accounts? For this situation - no, I have only one production account

Comment: no, the physical machine has the desktop application with the AD connection.  You can try it twice and see if it lets authentications with the same AD account from two different places.  If the AD settings don't let you dual login then there is no possible way to test this legitimately.  They need to provide the means to test it otherwise don't ask you to test it and assume the risk.